# Take difference between observations within same group with a reference observation

Tags: r, dplyr

```
test <- data.frame('prod_id'= c("shoe", "shoe", "shoe", "shoe", "shoe", "shoe", "boat", "boat","boat","boat","boat","boat"), 
               'seller_id'= c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a","g", "h", "r", "q", "b"), 
               'Dich'= c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
               'price' = c(120, 20, 10, 4, 3, 4, 30, 43, 56, 88, 75, 44)
                )
test

       prod_id seller_id Dich price
 1     shoe         a    1   120
 2     shoe         b    0    20
 3     shoe         c    0    10
 4     shoe         d    0     4
 5     shoe         e    0     3
 6     shoe         f    0     4
 7     boat         a    0    30
 8     boat         g    0    43
 9     boat         h    1    56
10     boat         r    0    88
11     boat         q    0    75
12     boat         b    0    44
```

So I would like to create a new column that takes the difference between observations in the price column based on the value of Dich where each observation takes its difference from the observation where Dich==1 within each prod_id group.

Here is my desired outcome below.

```
       prod_id seller_id Dich price diff_p
 1     shoe         a    1   120      0
 2     shoe         b    0    20     -100
 3     shoe         c    0    10     -110
 4     shoe         d    0     4     -116
 5     shoe         e    0     3     -117
 6     shoe         f    0     4     -116
 7     boat         a    0    30     -26
 8     boat         g    0    43     -13
 9     boat         h    1    56       0
10     boat         r    0    88      32
11     boat         q    0    75      19
12     boat         b    0    44     -12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'prod_id', take the difference of 'price' and 'price' where 'Dich' is 1

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
    group_by(prod_id) %>%
    mutate(diff_p = price - price[Dich == 1])
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   prod_id [2]
#   prod_id seller_id  Dich price diff_p
#   <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 shoe    a             1   120      0
# 2 shoe    b             0    20   -100
# 3 shoe    c             0    10   -110
# 4 shoe    d             0     4   -116
# 5 shoe    e             0     3   -117
# 6 shoe    f             0     4   -116
# 7 boat    a             0    30    -26
# 8 boat    g             0    43    -13
# 9 boat    h             1    56      0
#10 boat    r             0    88     32
#11 boat    q             0    75     19
#12 boat    b             0    44    -12
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, diff_p := price - price[Dich == 1], prod_id]
```

Comment: Awesome, I had thought that I either needed to use the select() function or subset but couldn't figure it out and my mind is tired (new baby). Cheers!

Comment: Quick question - I am getting an error "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `diff_p` must be length 20 (the group size) or one, not 0"

Comment: @DanielKreitzberg  Is the error related to having multiple 1's for a particular 'prod_id'?  Or do you have some 'prod_id' that have no 1s for 'Dich

Comment: @DanielKreitzberg  If the issue is related to no 1s in 'Dich' for a particular 'prod_id' `test %>% group_by(prod_id) %>% mutate(diff_p = if(any(Dich ==1)) price -price[Dich == 1] else price)`

Comment: If there are multiple 1s for 'Dich' in a 'prod_id', the condition is not clear

Comment: Oh thank you so much, this clarifies the issue. I'll have to check which one, if it is the case that there are some groups with multiple 1's and some with only 0 what would the solution be?

Comment: @DanielKreitzberg  If there are multiple 1s, it is not clear which one you take for the t difference from price

Comment: Oh yes I see so I would have to chose which Dich == 1 to subtract from. I suppose I can take the average of the Dich == 1's and then subtract the others from the average.

Comment: In that case, you can do `test %>% group_by(prod_id) %>% mutate(diff_p = if(any(Dich ==1)) price -mean(price[Dich == 1]) else price)`